# How can change the style of <ol> tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My question is small and simple so hope you'll understand it.

When we write `<ol><li></li></ol>` tag, its generated decimals by default like this:

> 1. abc
> 2. def
> 3. geh
>
> etc....

But I want to change the style of the `<ol><li></li></ol>` like this (very small change because my designer give me this):

> 1 - abc
>   2 - def
>   3 - gih
>
> etc....

So please tell me how can I achieve this design in `ol`.

Here is my CSS code:

```
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ol li {
    list-style: decimal;
}
```

Comment: you want to remove the "." and add a "-" ?

Comment: Haha, it was a race! Anyway, a reference to the answers posted below: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `counter-increment` property to achieve this. In the example below, I first reset the styles of `li` element to `none`, you can actually reset it on the `ol` itself.

Later, I set the `counter-increment` and I use the `content` property to feed in the values and the `-`.

```
ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: step-counter;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(step-counter) " - ";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/94yj11cm/)

I would suggest you to read more over [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) on MDN.

> Note: `step-counter` is a made up word, you can use anything you want
>   in that place, you can use like `custom-counter`, `dash-counter` or
>   anything you like.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with CSS `counter`. See this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;            
  content: counters(section,".") " - ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this css Code

```
ol{
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before { 
  content: counter(item) " -  "; 
  counter-increment: item 
}
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ze23vz7/)

Comment: Why the need to set `li` as `block`? Also, I believe OP wants space before the hyphen `1 - X` not `1- X`.